# Sharepoint WebMethod Session always null

Tags: jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2010

gGood day everyone. I'm having following issue:

1. I have webpart with some ajax
2. i have .ascx page for webmethods.

The problem is when i try to use any of following JS-functions:

```
function getSessionData() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/_layouts/MyProject/WebService.aspx/getSessionData',
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Do something interesting here.
            console.log(msg);
        }
        , error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log('error:');
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
}

function setSessionData(str) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/_layouts/MyProject/WebService.aspx/setSessionData',
        data: "{'id': '" + str + "' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Do something interesting here.
            console.log(msg);
        }
        , error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log('error:');
            console.log(xhr.status);
            console.log(thrownError);
        }
    });
}
```

with server-side code

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string getSessionData()
    {
        string wpsiid = "no data";
        try
        {
            wpsiid = HttpContext.Current.Session["wpsiid"].ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            wpsiid = "error occured";
            //throw;
        }
        return wpsiid;
    }

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string setSessionData(string id)
    {
        string ret = "ok";
        try
        {
            //HttpContext.Current.Session["wpsiid"] = id;
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("wpsiid",id);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            ret = "error...";
            //throw;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

i always get null reference exception.
So man question is how to fix it?